# Boost: is it any how possible to start a process and run a function in it?

Tags: c++, boost, process, interprocess

My main point is that let's say we create our main function of our app which lies in one project file. We have some static function in it like one with `cout << "Hello!";`. We want boost to create a process for us and run that function in it. Is such thing possible using boost and how to do it?

Comment: Windows? Linux? Process or thread?

Comment: Are you just trying to create an application that says `Hello`? or are you trying to create an application that starts another application to do the printing?

Comment: I wanted an app creating an app and running one of its functions...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Boost.Process](http://www.highscore.de/boost/process/) though it has not been accepted into the Boost distribution yet.

Comment: Grate. I love boost but how to solve for example this with it? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4774932/boost-process-how-to-make-a-process-run-a-function