# Encapsule boost process in a class

Tags: class, boost, process

I managed to encapsule boost.thread into a class, in which I have a boost::thread worker, that runs a method as threadCode

```
    boost::thread worker = boost::thread(boost::bind(&ThreadClass::executionLoop, this));
```

I want to do the same for a boost.process, in which a worker runs a method as independent process.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Note that boost.process is not part of boost. See this [community wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12327853) for a full list of all the different boost.process libraries.

Generally what you are trying to do isn't possible. There is a more elaborate discussion at [Boost.Process - how to make a process run a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4774932/), but since you can't make it run a function, you won't be able to neatly encapsulate it.